# Process started with systemctl throws no errors, but does not appear in process list?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

Unix newbie here. I am trying to start `gunicorn` with `systemctl`. No error message appears, but it's also not showing up in the processes list:

```
$ sudo systemctl start gunicorn
$ ps aux | grep gunicorn
test+ 29902  0.0  0.0  14224   924 pts/0    S+   11:13   0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

Is it possible that it's running, but invisible?

Or if not, how can I debug why it isn't running?

UPDATE: Just tried `systemctl status gunicorn` and got this:

```
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn Application Server handling myapp
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-10-31 11:24:04 EDT; 1min 25s ago
  Process: 30135 ExecStart=/.venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myapp/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 30135 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
```

So it's dead, but how can I find out why?

Comment: have you tried to run it yourself?, what about journalctl?

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
> ```

The working directory that you've configured in the service unit is wrong or inaccessible.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, it's correct, but make sure to check the permissions on parent directories also.

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar, I had all folders correctly present but got the same error.  I got it to work by changing the "User" parameter. I set it as root and worked. Fyi.